# Servo doesn't move properly

Tags: pwm, raspberry-pi, servo, jitter

I have a problem with my servo motor. I connected a servo to the PWA connection of a PCA9685, but powered the motor externally. There's no problem with that and it works fine with some smaller servo motors. But when I connect the exact same thing to the servo motors I actually want to use, the MC-410, then it doesn't work. Or, should I say, it works very spontaneously. Meaning that the servo moves only sometimes and then for a while not anymore.
The problem can't be the servos, I tested them directly with the Pi and they work, just not in my setup.

The whole thing is controlled by a Rasperry Pi 3 B+, the servos are powered with 6V, 1A.

If you have any questions, please ask, I'm happy to explain further

Comment: The first step I would take to debug this would be to hang a scope on the PWM signal and check how it looks: amplitude and mark/space ratio. Do you generate the PWM in software from the Pi?

Comment: I do not won a scope, so that i cannot do. And yes, I generate the signals from the Pi. The problem that bugs me more is why the smaller servo moves but the bigger doesn't

Comment: Generating PWM in SW on a Pi is unreliable. It maybe that the bigger one needs a signal with a better quality (closer to it's specification).  Have you checked the voltage levels? The Pi only produced 3.3Volts, maybe the big one needs 5V?

Comment: You do have a common ground, right?

Comment: That's why I connected the servos to an external power source, 6V, 1A, and they do have a common ground. I just can't explain myself why the small one moves but the big one doesn't

Comment: @Oldfart He is using a PCA9685 which is an I2C controlled free-running PWM driver. He is not generating the PWM in software on his RPI.

Comment: Do you have any evidence that your MC-410 works at all? Have you connected it to anything else and seen it work?

Comment: yes, when connected to the Pi directly it works perfectly

Comment: @YaKe69 That's pretty important information that you seemed to have left out of the original post: That driving the servo with the PC9685 does not work but driving it directly with the less reliable RPI outputs does. You can edit your original post to add in any missing info.

Comment: What PWM frequency and ratios are you using on the PCA9685?